# how to replace non LVM disk that is full, on the fly

Tags: rhel, filesystems, mount, backup, disk

we have rhel machine 7.2 version

disk `sdb` size is `3.9G`

and the following disk ( non LVM disk ) is full

```
/dev/sdb                   3997376    3911504   3911504   99% /hadoop
```

we add additional disk - `/dev/sdc` with `100G` and we create on this disk file system ext4

now we want to backup & restore the data from `/hadoop` on the new disk of 100G but the new disk also point to mount point folder - `/hadoop`

any suggestion how to perform this procedure ?

Comment: When you say "on the fly", does that mean you cannot unmount the existing /hadoop filesystem?

Comment: I think we not have choice so we need to do umount

Comment: You can't mount two filesystems at the same mount point. Or rather: You can, but the last mount will hide the first, and you can't see both filesystems at the same time. I would mount sdc on /hadoop2, copy the data, then unmount both sdb and sdc, then mount sdc on /hadoop. The switch from one filesystem to the other is almost instantaneous.